# Error "Error parsing document! " while parsing my XML

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

This my countries.xml file.

what is the problem pls answer me i am new to iOS.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
<countris>
<country>
    <countryname>india<countryname>    
</country>
</countris>
</plist>
```

this is my `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countris" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];


NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

Myparser *myParser = [[Myparser alloc] init];

[parser setDelegate:myParser];

BOOL success = [parser parse];

if (success)
{
    NSMutableArray *users = [myParser arraydata];
    NSString *log= [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"This is an array of User objects:\n\n%@",
                          [users description]];
    NSLog(log);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                message:@"Error parsing document!"
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

my Myparser.m file where i an implemantig my NSXMLParserDelegate protocol

```
#import "Myparser.h"
#import "MyParserData.h"

@implementation Myparser

@synthesize mydata,myparser,arraydata,flag,currentElementValue;

- (id) init {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
        arraydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        flag = FALSE;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countris"]) {
        return;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"]) {
        self.mydata  = [[MyParserData alloc] init];
         } else {
        self.currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (self.currentElementValue) {
        [self.currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parserdidEndElement:(NSString *)elementNamenamespaceURI:          (NSString *)namespaceURIqualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"counteis"]) {

        return;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"]) {
        [self.arraydata addObject:mydata];
        self.mydata = nil;
    } else {
        [self.mydata setValue:self.currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
    }

    self.currentElementValue = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: what is ur problem? if u didnt specify ur problem, how can we solve it?

Comment: @manujmv  I think the problem is there in the question title

Comment: Thanks for your help i git the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not valid. You have a `<countryname>` tag, but you never close it (i.e., you're missing the `/` in `</countryname>`).

When using `NSXMLParser`, I would suggest implementing [parseErrorOccurred](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-SW10) and then look at the error object and it will often give you insights as to where to look for the problem in your XML source. The Cocoa frameworks are generally pretty good about providing methods to get information about errors, so avail yourself of those techniques.

---

By the way, I notice that you appear to be trying to use a `plist` format, but it doesn't quite conform to the proper format, as if you're writing the XML by hand. Generally, if you're using `plist` files, you don't need to use a `NSXMLParser` at all (nor would you create the XML source manually).

Imagine the following source code:

```
NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"countries": @{@"country" : @"india"}};
[dictionary writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

This creates a `test.plist` file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>countries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>country</key>
        <string>india</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The thing is, once you create a plist using `writeToFile`, you can now read it as:

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary);
```

Clearly, if you're trying to learn how to use `NSXMLParser`, continue your experimentation. But when using `plist` files, you can simplify the process by just using `writeToFile` to save, and `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` to load.

By the way, this process works with not only `NSDictionary` objects, but `NSArray` objects, too. For example consider this array of dictionaries:

```
// create array plist

filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.plist"];
NSArray *array = @[@{@"country" : @"india"}, @{@"country" : @"france"}];
[array writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];

// read array plist

array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

But the idea is that you can save dictionaries and arrays in an XML format, without ever touching the XML source yourself, nor having to deal with `NSXMLParser`.

For more information, see the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html).

---

And, if your arrays and dictionaries contain custom objects, namely objects other than the standard Cocoa `NS` objects (such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, etc.), there is another technology called `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` that lets you write binary `plist` files, again using a XML format, but again sparing you from the details of writing XML source yourself, nor dealing with `NSXMLParser`. It's a bit more complicated and I wouldn't worry about it unless you're dealing with arrays/dictionaries with custom classes, but it's another wonderful abstraction that lets deal with XML files without ever having to deal with the XML itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
WRONG    <countryname>india<countryname>    
RIGHT    <countryname>india</countryname>
```

This causes error in parser and hence it hits the error delegate method.

The output logs the memory of parser which has nothing to do with result

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your countries.xml file, you doesn't close countryname, but open it again after actual name of a country.

Comment: thabks but my log output gives me "<MyParserData: 0xe280830>"